# Xpath - Using the logic within the count function

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, xpath, count

I am trying to use a true or fale statement within the count function of XPath and am encountering a few errors. Here is my code so far:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="all/courses/allcourses/course">

   <xsl:for-each select="student">

   <xsl:variable name="StudentTotalPoints" select="sum(results/u_points)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$StudentTotalPoints" />
    <xsl:variable name="amountEnrolled" select="count((360 - $StudentTotalPoints) != 0)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$amountEnrolled" />

        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

the XML code in question is:

```
   <all>
<courses>
    <allcourses>
    <course> 
        <c_code>U65</c_code>
        <c_title>Computer Science</c_title>
        <coursecp>360</coursecp>
        <student>
        <studentID>10265654</studentID>
        <fname>Sarah</fname>
        <lname>Clarke</lname>
        <results>
             <u_title>Communicating in an IT Environment</u_title>
                        <u_code>CSG1132</u_code>
                        <u_points>15</u_points>
                        <result>65</result>
                        <grade>CR</grade>
        </results>
<results>
             <u_title>Programming Principles</u_title>
                        <u_code>CSP1150</u_code>
                        <u_points>15</u_points>
                        <result>45</result>
                        <grade>N</grade>
        </results>
            </student>

<student> *same structure*  </student>
```

the problem is on the line where the variable amountEnrolled is declared, when trying to load the page in question I am welcomed with this error:

"Error during XSLT transformation: An XPath expression was expected to return a NodeSet."

So clearly the count function isn't returning anything. What is the best way to go about this? I feel like it should be simple but it definitely isn't. My required result is to count the amount of times that `360 - $StudentTotalPoints does NOT equal to 0`, how should I go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post enough code (XML + XSLT) to enable us reproduce the problem. Off the bat, `(360 - $StudentTotalPoints) != 0` is a boolean and not a node-set, thus cannot be counted.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have posted enough, the problem doesn't involve the other code, simply I am wondering how to perform Boolean logic within the count function.

@michael.hor257k Is it possible to perform boolean that can be counted? So in my case counting how many times `360 - $StudentTotalPoints does NOT equal to 0`

Comment: @michael.hor257k Ah sorry about that, well my required result is too count how many times `360 - $StudentTotalPoints does NOT equal to 0`, what is the best way to go about this? Sorry about my ignorance.

Comment: What @michael.hor257k is saying is that you should post an actual working example of what you're trying to do. It doesn't have to be your full XSLT/XML; just something we can work with (and that reproduces the issue). Otherwise it's a pain in the ass and you will get less help if you make it time consuming to answer an easy question.

Comment: @DanielHaley I've posted the required XML code, sorry about that guys. My fault.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sorry mate, I posted the required XML code, my fault.

Comment: I am afraid this is not quite clear. Can you have multiple `<u_points>` elements within a single student's results?

Comment: @michael.hor257k No, every <results> </results> will only contain one <u_points> but a student will have multiple <results> </results> within <student></student>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a student will have multiple `<results> </results>` within
>   `<student></student>`

Okay, then if we take the following example input:

```
<all>
    <courses>
        <allcourses>
            <course> 
                <c_code>U65</c_code>
                <student>
                    <studentID>1</studentID>
                    <results>
                        <u_points>10</u_points>
                    </results>
                    <results>
                        <u_points>20</u_points>
                    </results>
                    <results>
                        <u_points>30</u_points>
                    </results>
                </student>
                <student>
                    <studentID>2</studentID>
                    <results>
                        <u_points>40</u_points>
                    </results>
                    <results>
                        <u_points>50</u_points>
                    </results>
                    <results>
                        <u_points>360</u_points>
                    </results>
                </student>
            </course>   
        </allcourses>
    </courses>
</all>
```

and apply this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="all/courses/allcourses/course">
            <course code="{c_code}">
                <xsl:for-each select="student">
                    <student id="{studentID}">
                    <totalPoints><xsl:value-of select="sum(results/u_points)" /></totalPoints>
                    <amountEnrolled><xsl:value-of select="count(results/u_points[.!=360])" /></amountEnrolled>
                </student>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </course>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

we will receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <course code="U65">
      <student id="1">
         <totalPoints>60</totalPoints>
         <amountEnrolled>3</amountEnrolled>
      </student>
      <student id="2">
         <totalPoints>450</totalPoints>
         <amountEnrolled>2</amountEnrolled>
      </student>
   </course>
</root>
```

This is probably not what you want, but it does what you say it should do.

---

### Edit:

> Sorry, I forgot to specify, how many times within `<course>`

Okay, then we need to move the count to the parent Course element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="all/courses/allcourses/course">
            <course code="{c_code}">
                <xsl:for-each select="student">
                    <student id="{studentID}">
                        <totalPoints><xsl:value-of select="sum(results/u_points)" /></totalPoints>
                    </student>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <amountEnrolled>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(student[sum(results/u_points)!=360])"/>
                </amountEnrolled>
            </course>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If we now modify our input to:

```
<all>
    <courses>
        <allcourses>
            <course> 
                <c_code>U65</c_code>
                <student>
                    <studentID>1</studentID>
                    <results>
                        <u_points>10</u_points>
                    </results>
                    <results>
                        <u_points>20</u_points>
                    </results>
                    <results>
                        <u_points>30</u_points>
                    </results>
                </student>
                <student>
                    <studentID>2</studentID>
                    <results>
                        <u_points>40</u_points>
                    </results>
                    <results>
                        <u_points>50</u_points>
                    </results>
                    <results>
                        <u_points>270</u_points>
                    </results>
                </student>
            </course>   
        </allcourses>
    </courses>
</all>
```

we will receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <course code="U65">
    <student id="1">
      <totalPoints>60</totalPoints>
    </student>
    <student id="2">
      <totalPoints>360</totalPoints>
    </student>
    <amountEnrolled>1</amountEnrolled>
  </course>
</root>
```

Comment: Hey man, you've been a huge help! I appreciate all the effort you have put into this. That sort of answers my problem, but not really, probably bad wording on my part. So what I am aiming to do is see how many times `<totalPoints> does NOT equal to 360`, how would I go about implementing that? Definitely on the right track here, it's helped a ton.

Comment: How many times in *what*? We are currently in the context of `<student>` and each student has only a single total.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify, how many times within `<course>` so for example, in the example you provided, the answer would be 0 and 0 for both students.

Comment: You magnificent man, I have never met someone so talented at XML and XPath, thank-you good sir.